# Can Visual Studio be used to edit Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, visual-studio

I prefer Visual Studio to Xcode for text editing my Swift, but VS doesn't do such things as begin/end construct navigation (eg. I can't jump from opening { to closing } ).

My present project is actually a backend app on Windows, in .NET, and
the mobile in Swift on iOS.

Would be great to edit Swift on VS.

I don't want to run Swift on VS, just edit it.
I have my Mac files opened in VS, and a TeamViewer session remoting the Mac for compiling and then testing on my iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Although VS code is not quite your VS, you could give it a try ([here is how](https://nshipster.com/vscode/)).

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Even more recently, some bigger advancements in Swift plugins for VS Code: https://forums.swift.org/t/introducing-swift-for-visual-studio-code/54246 (Works quite well, from personal experience.)

Comment: Sergey:  even from VS on windows, remotely controlling the Xcode Mac?